# Выполнить скрипт если окно браузера меньше 1025px. Javascript

Tags: javascript

Нужно при ресайз/загрузки страницы с расширениям меньше 1025px выполнить скрипт.
У меня есть кусок кода на jQuery

```
 $(window).on('load resize', function () { 
   if ($(window).width() < 1025) {
   }
 });
```

Как сделать это на чистом JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Пример для проверки
  if (window.innerWidth < 1025) console.log('Ширина области меньше 1025px'); 

  window.onresize = function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1025) {
      console.log('Текущая ширина окна: ' + window.innerWidth + 'px');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! работает, а как еще добавить, чтобы при загрузке страницы в окне с расширениям меньше 1025px тоже выполнялся скрипт?

Comment: @SerhiyBilik, обновил.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте

```js
function addListenerMulti(element, eventNames, listener) {
  var events = eventNames.split(' ');
  for (var i=0, iLen=events.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    element.addEventListener(events[i], listener, false);
  }
}

addListenerMulti(window, 'resize DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    let w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    if(w > 1025) {
    alert("more than 1025 pixels ")
  }
});
```

Comment: как правильно добавить?

Comment: @SerhiyBilik отредактировал

Comment: а как совместить ресайз и загрузки в одну функцию?
Не хочется дублировать код дважды

Comment: @SerhiyBilik совместил